# How do I add a custom message on magento's checkout page(right below the Country selector) based on the country that user selects to ship the product?

Tags: magento2, php, javascript, requirejs

For example: If a user wants to ship to India, I want to show a small message below the country selector and before the shipping method saying that "custom duties and taxes has to be paid by customer". And for any other country "shipping is free".

Comment: are you using one page checkout?

Comment: @PareshaU Yes. I checked the Onepage.phtml file after enabling path-hints from the admin panel but could not understand how to make changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem.

```
Override -> module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/model/shipping-rates-validator.js
```

Copy paste the file into `Magento_Checkout/web/js/model/` into your theme folder. 
Add your changes in 'postcodeValidation' function.
Now every time you make any changes in the address attribute selectors, this function is called.

Answer (score 0):

Avishek, if you want to let any shopper outside of your domestic country know they are responsible for duties and taxes, there is an app on the Magento App store, [Zonos Hello](https://marketplace.magento.com/iglobal-zonos-hello.html). It will also estimate the duty and tax amount on the item pages. It is a free app. (You can also configure it to run in your checkout)

Comment: This app is for Magento 1. While the OP has asked about Magento 2.